# How to fix position an element but keep the height relative to browser window?

Tags: javascript, css

You probably noticed that some web sites have a feedback feature created with http://uservoice.com. It display's a badge on left or right of your screen.

But, how is that badge positioned? It looks like its position depends on the height of the browser....

Can you help me with how to create some sort of badge like this, with functionality to redirect me to the some other url?

tnx in adv!

Comment: How about the "Inspect Element" feature of Google Chrome?  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses `position: fixed` on the `a` tag. It is using a `top: 45%` to get it to "move" with the window height.

Comment: no, it's not fixed, tryed that before. it looks like it depends on browser's height. jquery maybe?

Comment: ... and no link to Firebug to save him/her the trouble of writing next time?

Comment: @user198003-Yes, it is 'fixed', with the top at 45%.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a cool example of css and JS for floating a link or menu!

[JTricks Example!](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html)

Heres another example from JTricks thats more like what your looking for (fixedmenu not floating)

[Another example!! =)](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/fixed_menu.html)

(shows legacy browser compatibility)